# Error : Not able to copy file from "obj\Debug\" to "bin\Debug\" folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, nunit

When I debug the project, I get the following error

Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\TestAutomation.dll" to "bin\Debug\TestAutomation.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\TestAutomation.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Getting this error:

[image: getting this error]

I have closed the locked file also from the Process Explorer but still getting the error .
How can I fix it?

I use Windows 8.1

Comment: Please do not put your entire question with details in the question title. Question body is there for this purpose

Comment: Make an exclusion for the build directory in your anti-malware product.  If it is aggressive shovelware like Avast then get rid of it completely.

Comment: @HansPassant This is also not working .

Comment: You need to find out which process has open handles of that file. I think this can be done using Process Explorer, but am not sure (did not do this for a while).

Comment: Did you try to restart VS? Sometimes this solves the Problem for me.

Comment: Yes I have restart VS many times but still not working at all @Sosian